# Forza Horizon 2 Cross-Platform Multiplayer on Xbox Systems?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, xbox-network, forza-horizon-2

My brother and I want to play Forza Horizon 2 on Xbox Live together. Since we have one Xbox One and one 360 Console, would it be possible for the two to play on Xbox Live together? Like how World Of Tanks allows cross platform multiplayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Forza Horizon 2 is not on the [backwards compatibility list](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/backward-compatibility) for Xbox One, this is no possible.  The game itself does not support cross platform play as far as I can tell - most games don't. It is not mentioned on any sites about the game.

Since the game was released for both consoles, it will never be added to this list either, making playing cross platform via the Xbox 360 emulator on Xbox One not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I honestly did not know there was a list of games for backwards compatabile games